# Woocommerce: populating a billing address field from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom field to the Woocommerce create new order page (admin) with this code:

```
function rt_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing_email'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Email' ),
        'show' => true,
        'class' => 'short',
    );

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'rt_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields');
```

My question is how do I then populate this new field when the page loads? I want to populate it from a URL token using

```
$email = get_query_var('email');
```

But how do I insert that value into the new field so it is visible to the admin while creating the order?

Answer (score 1):

To give a value to the field, change the `$field` to:

```
$email = get_query_var('email');
$fields['billing_email'] = array(
    'label' => __( 'Email' ),
    'value' => $email,
    'show' => true,
    'class' => 'short',
);
```

Comment: Ok that works. How do i change the value of an existing field?

Comment: If you are talking about the same WooCommerce hook, you can override the related field by providing an array with a value. Try.

Comment: I tried adding the element $fields['billing_first_name'] with value set to "Test" but it just creates a new field below the billing_email. How do I update the existing billing_first_name field? I tried both with and without a leading underscore.

Comment: I got it.. it is just $fields['first_name'] for anyone needed the same thing.

Comment: You can always check the documentation for available field names.

Comment: That's what I did, I looked up the function. Is there a way to do shipping fields too? woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields() doesn't seem to work.